# how to use google cloud compute engine

Tags: linux, deep-learning, google-compute-engine

i work on windows 10.
i have made a google cloud linux compute engine with 230gb standard persistent disk,1 GPU(tesla K80) ,13gb memory,2vCPU.
i have installed jupyter notebook and and all deeplearning frameworks and i am able to use it perfectly.
but i dont know how to access the data for deeplearning that is in my computer on the jupyter notebook running on my compute engine instance.
can anybody tell me how to use boot disk and what exactly its use is?
how to access data from my laptop?
I looked into the following links but couldnt understand the terminology.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#formatting
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/mount-ram-disks

Answer (score 1):

To clarify the terminology:

- **Persistent disk**: it is the same way you add a hard disk to your machine. If you add one more, you have to mount it somewhere inside your filesystem. (e.g. /media/data) You can find about making directory and mounting command on you mentioned documentation (down from 5.)
- **Ram disk**: it will treat extra disk as a memory space (e.g. for high performance computing). This is not consider as storage and will be count as tmpfs that doesn't keep data permanently. You may use if your task requires greater amount of RAM.

(disclaimer: I never use both extra persistent storage.)

In case you cannot find your data in Jupyter, it depends on the location you start jupyter notebook. For example, if you start Jupyter notebook at home directory, you will see data only in home directory. If you have a mounted drive, one way to access to that mount is making softlink to your working directory.

P.s. you can also use software like WinSCP to access to all file system apart from using only Jupyter.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to **set an ingress firewall rule** to **allow traffic** to the GCE instance.
In the console, go to:

- networking
- VPC network
- External IPs

Reserve a static IP address. 
Then go to:

- VPC network
- firewall rules

Create a **tag allowing** the **protocol tcp:9999** from source IP 0.0.0.0/0. 
When you create your instance, associate it with both the IP address and the firewall rule.

Here you can find more detailed instructions on how to create firewall rules on a GCP project: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls